# VS code appending special characters on paste

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm using VS code for editing javascript files. However I seem to see a bug when I go to copy and paste between files. Each time I paste I am getting a special character appended to the end of each line.

Has anyone else seen this problem? If so is there a fix?

Comment: for better solution provide some codes that you tire so far

Comment: Can you please include a screenshot?

Comment: There is nothing in particular that causes this issue, it happens occasionally when I paste.

Comment: @Hanoncs unfortunately stack overflow won't let me upload a screenshot, not enough points apparently.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a bug, Please file an issue at https://code.visualstudio.com/Issues. 
Screenshots, or code examples to reproduce this are appreciated!

Thanks a lot!